# initiate css transitions on page load

Tags: html, css

Im trying to understand CSS Transition - but I cant make it happen. I want to make a line go from 0 to 100% width with a small delay on pageload. I understand that CSs transition needs a trigger, and tried to read up to a jQuery or Vanilla Js solution, but get stuck.

Why is this ot working? Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1fzzgnwy/

```
<div class="container">
<span class="h-line"></span>
</div>

.h-line {
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
width: 0%;
height: 10px;
right: 0;
background-color: #000;
top: 400px;
transition: right 1.5s linear;
transition-delay: 2s;
}

.h-line.ready {
width: 100%;
background-color: #000;
}

.container {
height:100%;
width:100%;
}

$(function(){
$('.h-line').addClass('ready');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your transition line, you are telling it to transition `right`, but that doesn't change in the added class. Your `width` does. So you need to transition the width like `transition: width 1.5s linear;`: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1fzzgnwy/2/)

And if you want it to expand left to right, remove `right: 0`: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1fzzgnwy/3/)

Comment: Ah now i get it . Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In your jsfiddle link (https://jsfiddle.net/1fzzgnwy/) there are some errors.

Here a simplified example of your code that work https://jsfiddle.net/50t3qwmL/ .

```css
    .h-line {

        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;

        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;

        background-color: #000;
        transition: .3s;
        transition-delay: 2s;

    }

    .h-line.ready {

        width: 100%;

    }
```